# Android studio seekbar color

Tags: android, seekbar

With this code :

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:max="4"
    android:progress="0"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="10dp"
    android:theme="@style/MySeekBar" />


<style name="MySeekBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar">
    <item name="android:progressBackgroundTint">#F1F1F1</item>
    <item name="android:progressTint">#A9A9A9</item>
    <item name="android:thumbTint">#42221F1F</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlActivated">#FF0000</item>
</style>
```

I managed to get this :

https://i51.servimg.com/u/f51/12/22/36/57/screen37.jpg

But when I move the seekbar, I can see an orange bigger circle like this :

https://i51.servimg.com/u/f51/12/22/36/57/screen36.jpg

And was not able to change the orange color to another one.
How can I do this ?